# Linux and Windows 10 Dual-Boot problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I decided to make Dual-Boot. I have 120Gb SSD and 500Gb HDD. Windows 10 is in SSD and I allocated HHD in two 250Gb partitions. So I installed Linux in that 250Gb partition.

EasyBCD: EasyBDC tells me that it can't add new entry of boot option because of UEFI system.

BIOS boot option: If i want to go to linux I have manually change boot-able drive, in my case HDD. In GRUB 2 menu there is no Windows option.

So my question is how can I add Windows 10 to grub2 menu or how can I add Linux to Windows 10 efi boot?

Answer (score 1):

In linux, I use disk repair with the option "fix windows efi" files checked and it reinstated grub as my boot manager with Ubuntu and Windows as options to load.

Comment: oh yeah I forgot, I also checked the option to move/rename windows efi files

Comment: ok somehow I didn't read your question correctly. To have grub 2 be the default boot manager, use disk repair. To have windows be the boot manager, use bcdedit.